# How to say "work" in venezuelan spanish

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, venezuela

How would i say the word "work", (as in, "i have to go to work") in Venezuela?

Comment: I think this answer (as is posted right now) would be easily answered checking the dictionary. Could you please elaborate a little bit more so we can understand what is giving you trouble and we are able to help you with something specific (and not just check the dictionary for you?). See [ask]

Answer (score 3):

Según la página [Wiki Lengua palabras de Venezuela](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Palabras_de_Venezuela)

> Trabajo, empleo = chamba. Como no le dieron chamba, asaltó el negocio.